# How to count the output of the steps needed to complete the program

Tags: java, random, hash

Hi i have this program and i want to count and print  the total steps that needed to complete the program when i'm running it 10 times. (count the total console lines)

**Any advice is appreciated**

The code of the Hash Table:

```
public class HashFunction {

String[] theArray;
int arraySize;
int itemsInArray = 0;
    int K = 0;

/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


HashFunction theFunc = new HashFunction(101);

String[] elementsToAdd2 = new String[101];

for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
elementsToAdd2[i] = Integer.toString(RandomNumbers.getRandomNumberInRange(0, 15024267));
}



    theFunc.hashFunction2(elementsToAdd2, theFunc.theArray);

}


public void hashFunction2(String[] stringsForArray, String[] theArray) {

    for (int n = 0; n < stringsForArray.length; n++) {

        String newElementVal = stringsForArray[n];

        // Create an index to store the value in by taking
        // the modulus

        int arrayIndex = Integer.parseInt(newElementVal) % 101;

        System.out.println("P" + arrayIndex + " " + "I" + newElementVal + "@" + arrayIndex );

        // Cycle through the array until we find an empty space

        while (theArray[arrayIndex] != "-1") {

            ++arrayIndex;

            System.out.println( "P" + arrayIndex);

            // If we get to the end of the bucket go back to index 0

            arrayIndex %= arraySize;

        }

        theArray[arrayIndex] = newElementVal;

    }

}

HashFunction(int size) {

    arraySize = size;

    theArray = new String[size];

    Arrays.fill(theArray, "-1");

}
```

}

Program to run the class 10 times:

```
public class RunTenTimes
    {
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
          HashFunction.main(args); 
  }
}
```

Should i add the code in the main class  or in the RunTenTimes Class?

Comment: How exactly do you define "step"?

Comment: What do you mean the *the total steps*?

Comment: i mean count, the trace of operations needed to insert the randomly generated keys, one
by one, into an initially empty 101-bucket hash table

Comment: Please give examples. Can you identify the code lines which define a step? Can you name all the code lines for each step?

Comment: i want to  count the  hash table operations, for instance here `P19 I9526036@19
P20
P21
P2I11651766@2` i have 5 operations printed out i want to have some code to print out "Number of steps required: 5"